# SQL Server 2014 - AlwaysOn HA - Always Synchronizing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, high-availability

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 cluster with SQL Server 2014 configured in a HA configuration.

The secondary databases always say `Synchronizing` when the data movement is happening. Is this normal? Should it say synchronized at some point?

Comment: What is the mode of Always on availability group configuration? Synchronous or Asynchronous?

Comment: Asynchronous Commit

Comment: I'm reading about that here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877931.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have configured AlwaysON as Asynchronous, it will be in `synchronizing` state.

> Should it say Synchronized at some point?

If you want to do a planned failover, you should `alter` your availablity group to `synchronous` and then do a failover.

When you change the synchronization method to `synchronous` and when the secondary has catch-up with primary, it will show `synchronized`.

Refer  to my answer : [How far is secondary behind primary ?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63870/8783) as well as AlwaysON professional blog - [Determine Availability Group Synchronization State, Minimize Data Loss When Quorum is Forced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2014/11/11/determine-availability-group-synchronization-state-minimize-data-loss-when-quorum-is-forced/)